# How is recommended to use asserts in Cypress

Tags: cypress

How do you use the asserts in Cypress, in your project? Step and assert in same step (it()) or in a different (it())?

1:

```
describe('test', ()=> {
    it('clicks on button "Add new user"', ()=> {
        // click action
        
        // assert (should()) modal to add new user is opened
    })
})
```

or

2:

```
describe('test', ()=> {
    it('clicks on button "Add new user"', ()=> {
        // click action
    })
    
    it('Expect: modal should be opened', ()=> {
        // assert (should()) modal to add new user is opened
    })
})
```

In Protractor I have used like on no. 1, with action method and expect method inside same it(), but in Cypress you can't add custom messages for should() asserts, to see exactly what is failing. (eg. 'modal should be opened')

Thank you!

Comment: Each test should work independently, so way nr 2 is an antipattern.

Comment: The errors raised by Cypress in case of failure are quite descriptive. I do not see a reason to use this anti-pattern presented in 2.